# What is the one or the few major changes from Java 6 to Java 7, couldn't JBoss do that already with Java 5?

Tags: java, resources, jboss

A buddy said today that one change between v6 and v7 is that v7 will close for instance database connection "automatically" but couldn't JBoss do that already with Java 5? I've seen "JBoss is closing the connection for you." in the JBoss' logs many years ago with Java 5 (or even 4). What do you think? I almost read the same question here but not exactly:

[How to justify migration from Java 6 to Java 7?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/204711/how-to-justify-migration-from-java-6-to-java-7)

The answer to the question above does not list the feature we were talking about this morning. What did my buddy mean? What do you think is the one or the few major technical changes? I understand Java 6 has not even support anymore but that is a policy and not the diff analyses  between v6 and v7.

Comment: this is `try-with-resources` feature, explained in details in at least two of the answers in the _justify migration_ question you refer to ([1](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/204759/31260), [2](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/204716/31260))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That feature name is [automatic resource management](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-February/000011.html) of the [Project Coin](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/project_coin_final_five) it works for streams and connections:

```
static void copy(String src, String dest) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        try {
            byte[] buf = new byte[8 * 1024];
            int n;
            while ((n = in.read(buf)) >= 0)
                out.write(buf, 0, n);
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Becomes:

```
static void copy(String src, String dest) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
         OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest)) {
        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
        int n;
        while ((n = in.read(buf)) >= 0)
            out.write(buf, 0, n);
    }
}
```